# How to make variable in companion object protected

Tags: kotlin, protected, companion-object

I want to make a variable in companion object protected. I think when I make the variable protected, it would be accessible only from another class which inherit the variable's class, not from other classes or functions. But It doesn't work.
Here's my code

```
open class Population{
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic // Though I added it because of recommendation of IntelliJ, It still doesn't work.
        protected var population_quantity: Int = 0
    }
}

class Marin : Population(){
    init{
        population_quantity += 1 // I want to make it possible
    }
}

class Checker : Population() {
    fun printPopulationQuantity()
    {
        println(population_quantity) // I also want to make it possible
    }
}

fun main(){
    var m1 = Marin()
    var checker = Checker()

    // But I want to make codes below here impossible
    // Population.population_quantity += 1
    // println(Population.population_quantity)
}
```

Below is what I want to make which is made via C++. I hope below would clarify what I'm saying.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Population
{
    protected:
        static int population_quantity;
};
int Population::population_quantity = 0;

class Marin : Population
{
    public:
        Marin()
        {
            std::cout << "Marin is generated" << std::endl;
            population_quantity += 1;
        }
        ~Marin()
        {
            std::cout << "Marin is dead" << std::endl;
            population_quantity -= 1;
        }
};

class Checker : Population
{
    public:
        void printPopulationQuantity()
        {
            std::cout << population_quantity << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Checker checker;
    checker.printPopulationQuantity();
    Marin *m1 = new Marin();
    checker.printPopulationQuantity();
    
    // std::cout << "population : " << Population::population_quantity << std::endl;
    // Can't access population_quantity from main which doesn't inherite Population
    // because Population::population_qantity is protected.
    // But it is possible to access Population:population_quantity from Marin which inherits Population.

    delete m1;
    checker.printPopulationQuantity();
    return 0;
}
```

When you help me solve this problem, I'm sure that I would feel sincere thankful from bottom of my heart.

Comment: what it has to do with c++?

Comment: @ÖöTiib If you are refering about tag, I just added it for highlighting C++ code properly. If it is impropriate to add C++ tag just for this purpose, I'll remove it.

Comment: Oh. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to indicate highlighting language for different code snippets differently.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because in `class Checker : Population` you have a void function which is in `public`.
Try changing it to this:

```
class Checker : Population
{
    protected:
        void printPopulationQuantity()
        {
            std::cout << population_quantity << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Comment: Does your answer mean that removing `class Checker : Population` could solve this problem?  I'm so sorry but when removing `class Checker : Population`, it still doesn't work, leaving the same error message `Kotlin: Using non-JVM static members protected in the superclass companion is unsupported yet`.

Comment: There we go. I've edited it to explain what I mean

Comment: Oh now I see what was your meaning. At first, thank you for your help. But I didn't intend to ask about C++. Maybe my wrong tag-selection make you confused. I asked about kotlin. I added C++ code which runs well to exemplify what I intended.

Comment: In that case, have a read of this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#class-members